# Is there a way to keep an Reactive Stream open forever on Spring Reactive using Rsocket, Websocket or Http?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive, r2dbc, rsocket

I want to connect a client on a server to receive a Flux of some entity and keep then connected (In a non-blocking + Assynchronous fashion) in order to receive updates or new insertions in the same Flux.

In other words I want that DB inform the server when there are some update or new data. The server to inform the client. All in a assynchronous + non-blocking fashion.

I tried with spring-boot-starter-webflux, with plain http, also tried spring-boot-starter-rsocket, with rsocket.

Tried with redis, mongo and now postgresql.

The only way it worked almost as expected was with MongoDB capped colelction + tailable stream. But in this way the collection is capped and I can't edit an existing entry.

Are you aware about some approach to accomplish that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to continues send data from backend to frontend when something changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71395004/how-to-continues-send-data-from-backend-to-frontend-when-something-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Use the spring-boot-starter-rsocket, create a MessageMapping endpoint and the server listen to a topic with reactive-redis, thus there are message data channel.

Comment: Thank you very much @echooymxq but the RSocket channel is also not keeping the stream open. They conclude as soon as all the current existing data is retrieved.

I was able to keep it exchange messages by using a Flux.interval. But I am not happy. I would like something else, more reactive.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues For rsocket, it is easy to get infinite stream using the `request/stream` mode, check my [article of building a chat application](https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-chat-application-with-angular-and-spring-rsocket-3cd8013f2f55), the sample codes links are available in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres includes a Notifier/Listener pattern to track the messages on database, for example.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
class Listener {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pgConnectionFactory")
    ConnectionFactory pgConnectionFactory;

    PostgresqlConnection receiver;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        receiver = Mono.from(pgConnectionFactory.create())
                .cast(PostgresqlConnection.class)
                .block();

        receiver.createStatement("LISTEN mymessage")
                .execute()
                .flatMap(PostgresqlResult::getRowsUpdated)
                .log("listen::")
                .subscribe();

        receiver.getNotifications()
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .log()
                .subscribe(
                        data -> log.info("notifications: {}", data)
                );
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        receiver.close().subscribe();
    }

}
```

The whole example is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/boot/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java).

As you mentioned,  with Mongo capped collections, it is easy to emit the item to a reactive Flux sink, check my fullstack(frontend+backend) example of [Http/SSE](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-sse-sample), [WebSocket](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-websocket-sample), [RSocket](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-rsocket-sample).

You can emit any data to a connnectable flux by your own logic, such as emitting data by fine-grained domain events, this usage is more generic in real world projects.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class PostService {
    //...
    public Mono<Comment> addComment(CommentInput commentInput) {
        String postId = commentInput.getPostId();
        return this.posts.findById(UUID.fromString(postId))
                .flatMap(p -> this.comments.create(commentInput.getContent(), UUID.fromString(postId)))
                .flatMap(id -> this.comments.findById(id).map(COMMENT_MAPPER))
                .doOnNext(c -> {
                    log.debug("emitting comment: {}", c);
                    sink.emitNext(c, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new PostNotFoundException(postId)));
    }

    private final Sinks.Many<Comment> sink = Sinks.many().replay().latest();

    public Flux<Comment> commentAddedEvent() {
        return sink.asFlux();
    }
}
```

Any of your client can connect to this `commentAddedEvent`. For example, the following is using SSE.

```java
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Comment> commentsStream(){
    this.postService.commentAddedEvent();
}
```

Similarly, if you are using WebSocket, use a [WebSocketHandler to adapt it](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-websocket-sample/blob/feat/reactor-sinks/server/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/WebSocketServerApplication.kt#L42-L67), and for RSocket, use [a controller with messaging mapping route](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-rsocket-sample/blob/master/server/src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/RSocketServerApplication.kt#L37-L39) instead.